# issues with dynamically generated options for select

Tags: jquery, html-select, selectedvalue

So I have a simple page (html) where using jquery I load 's into a select using a php file.
The code is as follows:
The HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pg_invoicedtl">
  <header data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a href="javascript:history.go(0)" data-icon="refresh" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="e">Refresh</a>
    <h1>MyApp</h1>
  </header>

    <div align="center" data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Select product</h3>
            </li>            

            <li>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="prodselect" class="select">Choose the product:</label>
                <select name="prodselect" id="prodselect">
                </select>
            </div>            
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script (located of course in the HEAD section) that I use to populate the select is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup ({
                cache: false
            });

            var ajaxLoader = '<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading.." />'; 
            var loadUrl = "loadproducts.php";  


            $('#prodselect').toggle('fast', function() {
                $(this).html(ajaxLoader);
                $(this).toggle('fast', function() {
                    $.get(loadUrl, function(data){
                        $('#prodselect').html(data);
                    },'html');                  
                });
            });
            $('#prodselect').selectmenu('refresh');
        });        
</script>
```

And now the php file (loadproducts.php) that the script is calling:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "/tmp/conexiune.php";

$pql = mysql_query("select * from products order by name");
$isfirst = 0;
while ($prow = mysql_fetch_row($pql)){
    if ( $isfirst == 0){
        echo '<option id="'.$prow['idproducts'].'"value="'.$prow['name'].'" selected="selected">'.$prow['name'].' - '.$prow['pu'].' EUR</option>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option id="'.$prow['idproducts'].'"value="'.$prow['name'].'">'.$prow['name'].' - '.$prow['pu'].' EUR</option>';
    }
    $isfirst++;
}    
?>
```

First I must tell you that the above code works. With one problem though... My problem...:

- As you may observe from the code, I want the first option of the select to be "selected", but no matter what I do, it does not happen. The select box is empty after refreshing the page, and if I want to select the first option in the list using the mouse, it does nothing, just as if the first item would be selected already so it does not do it.
- If I want to select the second or other option in the list, all works fine.
- So the first element of the select seems to be selected but it does not display it's value in the select box.
- I even added the $('#prodselect').selectmenu('refresh'); to the script with no result...
- Also, everything works perfect if I use non-dinamically generated options. So for static Options, the select displays the first Option from the very beginning.

  I do not understand what could be wrong. I tested the php file outside the HTML (without calling it from the script) and the result looks just like a perfect select content, and when put inside the select TAGs it displays the perfect result. But when I call it from the script something gets messed up.

  I would put a jsfiddle here but I don't think it works with php files...

Comment: Have you tried $('#prodselect).selectmenu('refresh', true);

Comment: I did try it. Does not work. If you have access to a PHP+MySql environment try it yourself. It's just a simple products table, a short php file and the simple HTML above. You should be able to reproduce my problem easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $('#prodselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

After loading dynamic content you need to force rebuild the select as mentioned in the document :
http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

Comment: I did try it like this too. It looks like it wont refresh... I even placed alerts before and after calling the refresh method to see if it fires. And it does. But the refresh is not happening

Comment: @CalinM try to call after the  $('#prodselect').html(data); line

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the solution. I placed the refresh after the `$('#prodselect').html(data);` line and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `===` (note 3) rather than `==`.

If this does not work then change:

```
$isfirst = 0;
```

to

```
$isfirst = 1;
```

As `0` can evaluate as false in cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did change that too. But it is not from the php, because as I said before, I launched the php file directly in the browser, and viewed the page source. And in the source, the options get shown perfectly ... with the first one with selected in it.

Comment: This is my output when calling the php directly: `<option id="3" value="Prod1" selected="selected">Prod1-150.00 EUR</option><option id="1" value="Prod3">Prod3</option><option id="2" value="Product new">Product new</option>` So as you may see, the first option is **selected**