# Generate Select List Item Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Generate Dynamic Select List Item Menu using JQuery

Here is the Div :

```
<select name="CountryID" id="CountryID">
<option value="" id="">Select the Country</option>
......
</option>
</select>
<div id='result' name="result">
<select  id="name">
<option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id='resulta' name="resulta">
<select  id="name">
<option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here is my Script :

```
<script>
var ab=$.noConflict();
ab(document).ready(function(){
ab("#CountryID").change(function(){
    var CountryID=ab("#CountryID").val();
    ab.post("globalregiongenerator",
    {
      CountryID:CountryID
    },
    function(data,status){
       ab( "#result" ).html( data );
    });
  });
});
</script>


<script>
var ac=$.noConflict();
ac(document).ready(function(){
  ac("#RegionName").change(function(){
  //alert('action triggered');
    var RegionName=ab("#RegionName").val();
    ac.post("globalcitygenerator",
    {
      RegionName:RegionName
    },
    function(data,status){
       ac( "#resulta" ).html( data );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Here i generate my Select Menu List

```
public function globalregiongenerator()
    {
    $CountryID = Input::get('CountryID');
    $roles = DB::table('region')->where('CountryID', $CountryID)->lists('regionname','regionid');   
    echo "<select  id='RegionName' name='RegionName'>"; 
    foreach ($roles as $value) 
    {
    echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
    }
    }

public function globalcitygenerator()
    {
    $RegionName = Input::get('RegionName');
    $roles = DB::table('city')->where('RegionName', $RegionName)->lists('regionname','regionid');   
    echo "<select  id='CityName' name='CityName'>"; 
    foreach ($roles as $value) 
    {
    echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
    }
    }
```

I can able to generate the First Select Menu List Item, But the action       `ac("#RegionName").change(function(){` is not triggering, even i tried putting alert inside it.

Is the Second List Menu Item `<select  id='RegionName' name='RegionName'>` not creating in the page or what.

How can i do this ?

Note :

I even tried  `ab('#RegionName').selectmenu('refresh', true);` under the `ab( "#result" ).html(data);` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551301/3492495) but it didn't worked

### Update :

If we append `$( "#result" ).append ( data );` another menu will appear, that isn't i need. 
I need to the first three menu already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not closing `<select`, I think you need `echo </select>` as well. For the handler try

```
ac(document).on("click", "#RegionName"
```

You also have a `var RegionName=ab("#RegionName").val();` which should be `var RegionName=ac("#RegionName").val();`

**update:**

line should be

`RegionName=ac(this).val();`

**Update2**

Change

```
echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
```

Comment: I changed the var as you told, But will the RegionName=ac("#RegionName").val(); have the value of option select that is being generated ?

Comment: @Stackerman Use `$(this).val();`.  `$(this)` is the element that fired the event.

Comment: I updated, var RegionName=ac("#RegionName").val(); but it is always returning the first value of the option select :(

Comment: @Stackerman Once you generate the html check if it's in the correct format, `ac(this).val();` should work. Have you closed `<`select>`?

Comment: Yes, even i closed the <select>

Comment: Just now i noted that it is returning only the first set of the element i mean For United States it return only United, What might be the problem ?

Comment: @Stackerman See the 2nd update. I think it's malformed option.

Comment: Thanks a loads, just now i adjusted in the server side.

Comment: I can repeat the select option list for n times right ??

Comment: @Stackerman Not sure what you mean but shouldn't matter how many options there are inside `select`. If you mean adding multiple `select`s, then make sure they have different ids, and bind to different ids.

Comment: Yes, i mean to add multiple select, for sure i will have different id's and bind to it

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic elements we should use delegated events:

Change `ac("#RegionName").change(function(){ /* handler body */ })`

To `ac(document).on("change","#RegionName",function(){ /* handler body */ })`

---

Also Change `ab("#CountryID").change(function(){ /* handler body */ })`

To `ab(document).on("change","#CountryID",function(){ /* handler body */ })`

---

To get selected value, you can do like below within the function

```
ab(document).on("change","#CountryID",function(){ 
    var countryId = ab(this).val();
    //or like => var countryId = ab(":selected", this).val(); 

    /* Rest of code */ 
})
```

Correct below statement in server side you have to enclose `value` in quotes

```
echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
```

Comment: Yes working, but i am not getting the value of inside the option select that is generated from the select menu list, How can i get the value of the option select that is generated from the select menu?  I am always getting the first value returned

Comment: Correct option building in your server side and try that should work, see updates

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted in the Server Side.. I would +1 if i have 15 rep