# JQuery Dynamic Option Select Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-4

This is the continution of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26924939/3492495)

Here is the Code for Dynamic JQuery Option Select Generator.

First i will choose the Country, which i didn't include the code, it will return the CountryID which is passed to the controller, then RegionID, then CityID. IT works well until generating the CityID Option select Menu, while i move to the AreaID it didn't work.

**What i am missing and how can i fix that ?**

I can't able to generate the Menu after the third Second One.

**Here is the HTML :**

```
<div id='result' name="result">
<select  id="name">
<option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id='resulta' name="resulta">
<select  id="name">
<option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id='resultb' name="resultb">
<select  id="name">
<option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
```

Here is my Script :

```
<script>
  var ab = $.noConflict();
  ab(document).ready(function() {
    ab(document).on("change", "#CountryID", function() {
      var CountryID = ab("#CountryID").val();
      ab.post("globalregiongenerator", {
          CountryID: CountryID
        },
        function(data) {
          ab("#result").html(data);
        });
    });

  });
</script>


<script>
  var ac = $.noConflict();
  ac(document).ready(function() {
    ac(document).on("change", "#RegionName", function() {
      var RegionName = ac("#RegionName").val();
      ac.post("globalcitygenerator", {
          RegionName: RegionName
        },
        function(data) {
          ac("#resulta").html(data);
        });
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
  var ad = $.noConflict();
  ad(document).ready(function() {
    ad(document).on("change", "#CityName", function() {
      var CityName = ad("#CityName").val();
      ad.post("globalareagenerator", {
          CityName: CityName
        },
        function(data) {
          ad("#resultb").html(data);
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**And here is the Server Side :**

```
public function globalregiongenerator()
    {
    $CountryID = Input::get('CountryID');

    $result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM region where CountryID =$CountryID");
    echo "<select  id='RegionName' name='RegionName'> <option value='' id=''>Select the Area</option>"; 
    foreach ($result as $value) 
    {
    echo "<option value=".$value->RegionID.">".$value->RegionName."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    }

    public function globalcitygenerator()
    {
    $RegionID = Input::get('RegionName');
    $result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM city where RegionID =$RegionID");
    echo "<select  id='CityName' name='CityName'> <option value='' id=''>Select the Area</option>"; 
    foreach ($result as $value) 
    {
    echo "<option value=".$value->CityID.">".$value->CityName."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    }

    public function globalareagenerator()
    {
    $CityID = Input::get('CityName');
    $result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM area where CityID =$CityID");
    echo "<select  id='CityName' name='CityName'> <option value='' id=''>Select the Area</option>"; 
    foreach ($result as $value) 
    {
    echo "<option value=".$value->CityID.">".$value->CityName."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    }
```

Note :

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

This is the error i got in console

Comment: Just a side note: `$.noConflict` will not work if there is a conflict with `$` (it should have been `jQuery.noConflict()`). You can use the *shortcut DOM ready handler* `jQuery(function($){ YOUR CODE USING A LOCAL $ });` to also provide a locally scoped `$` to your code.

Comment: Please do a "save-as" from the page in your browser, and show us the generated HTML that jQuery sees. :)

Comment: @TrueBLueAussie : Should i replace all the elements of $.noConflict with jQuery.noConflict ?

Comment: Simpler & smarter to use this DOM ready handler syntax instead: `jQuery(function($){ YOUR CODE USING A LOCAL $ });` (but, yes you can just use `jQuery.noConflict()`)

Comment: Thanks i follow your advice and my issue "Undefined" error was overcome.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo "<option value=".$value->CityID.">".$value->CityName."</option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='".$value->CityID."'>".$value->CityName."</option>";
```

Same with other echos. You're generating

```
<option value=united states>United States</option>
```

but it needs to be

```
<option value='united states'>United States</option>
```

**Update:**

Change them to

```
echo "<option value=\"".$value->CityID."\">".$value->CityName."</option>";
```

Comment: *Double-quotes* on attributes are recommended for best compatibility with HTML standards. Use single-quotes on the outside strings when generating HTML (or delimit inside `"`s with `\"`).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Didn't know that, I thought `value='states'` was the same as `value="states"`. Also I've never used php so I wasn't sure if you can use single quote on the php side.

Comment: I updated to all echo "<option value='".$value->RegionID."''>".$value->RegionID."</option>";as you said, but still it has error the same error as  - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: `"` or `'` *will* work on most browsers, but best to stick to `"`. Use `\"` if you cannot use single-quote on the string literal. Also a lot of tools cannot cope with single-quoted attributes.

Comment: @Stackerman See the update. Also in your comment you have an extra single quote.

Comment: I have cleaned up my code, and i found that i have error in the last script - > var ad=$.noConflict();.... Is there any error in that, or shall i create script like that ?

Comment: @Stackerman Actually, you don't need 3 separate `<script>`s. Combine them into a single `<script>` and call `var ab = $.noConflict();` once and use `ab` in all 3 functions. Also see the comment by TrueBlueAussie under your question, suggesting to use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Yes, i changed it according to the advice, But while i choose 1st, 2nd and 3rd selection list accordingly When i change the 1st selection list, the 3rd selection list should be reset , is there any other option rather than ab('#RegionName').selectmenu('refresh', true); ?

Comment: Try `ab('#RegionName').val("");`